# Is there a visual output of a trigger? How do I know my trigger is working?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to triggers. My trigger is suppose to fire when a new guest is added to the guest table in the database, updating the guest count, then upon deleting guests, the guest count will subtract one from the guest count.

From what I understand, the whole reason to have the triggers is to be able to view the total guest count at any time. My question is where or how do I see this? I am using phpmyadmin (bitami).

Comment: SQL doesn't produce any output by itself. The only output you get is the result of queries.

Comment: If you want to know if the trigger is working, query `totalguests`, perform an insert or delete on `guests`, then query `totalguests` again to see if the count changed.

Comment: when I query totalguests I get an empty result set, using SELECT * FROM `totalguests`  Is this what you mean? Please forgive me, I am just learning.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE totalguests(guestCount INT NOT NULL);`  This is what I used to create the table, but when I select the table totalguests I get an empty result. Shouldn't guestCount show?

Comment: If the table is empty, what are you expecting to update with `SET guestcount = guestcount + 1`?

Comment: You need to insert a row in the `TotalGuests` table, so that the `UPDATE` statement has something to update.

Comment: Why do you need this table? If you want to find out the number of guests, use `SELECT COUNT(*) from guest`

Comment: I edited my comment above Barmar. The table does have guestCount, but when I click on totalguests I get an empty result. I guess I have done something wrong. I am completing a diploma, but my tutor is on holidays for another week. She assured me all my code was correct, but something is amiss.

Comment: RESOLVED. THANK YOU Barmar. I was trying to show the guestcount on totalguests, when I should have been doing it on guest. I think I have been looking at this too long. It is so clear now. Thank you again.